# TCP/IP Monitoring in Eclipse-Stub based client call

Tags: eclipse, tcp, soapui, stub

I generated Web service client using the given WSDL in Eclipse. I have written a main method to invoke the Proxy class for getting the response.

https://val-p1-all-vim:8080/Selfcare/address?wsdl

I want to see the request that am making for debugging. I don't know what to configure as a Local monitoring port.
Local monitoring port: ?
Host name: val-p1-all-vim
Port: ?
Type: ?

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You are free to choose a port that is not in use on your system like 8080. In your program change server to localhost:, e.g. localhost:8080.
A problem is that you can't connect to https. Your web service should also allow http.